# Display BMP in JLabel

Tags: java, image, bmp

Java can display png, jpg a some other picture formats, but i have to display a bmp file in a JLable by getting the file path.

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

ImageIcon support the typical `png,gif,jpg` images.

In the project i am working, i can not open a bmp file and store the same file as a jpg, because i am not allow to store something at runtime. I could only generate the image in hold it in memory. But i dont know how to do this.

How can i show `BMP` in `Java` `1.4`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find some classes written in Java 1.5 but you can easily update 2 classes so that you can use the classes in 1.4.

[imag4j](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=181651&package_id=210461) can convert bmp and ico files to BufferedImage objects you can display in java.
You can import 17 classes and have to update maybe 10 lines because of java 1.5 statements.

You get a bmp converter which is working very fine.

Answer (score 10):

[javax.imageio.ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) supports the BMP format:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
```

ImageIO can also be used to convert between different formats.

Comment: ImageIO.read(imageFile) is returning null when the image is a bmp file

Comment: There's no built-in BMP support until Java 5.

Comment: I have been figuring out why my implementation was not working for few hours...and now I realize that loading bmp file directly does not work..