# Java support Couldn't figure out

Tags: java

looked at this post couldn't really figure it out:

[Display BMP in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593830/display-bmp-in-jlabel)

Answer (score 4):

How about you give this approach a try.

Reference: [Java Tip 43: How to read 8- and 24-bit Microsoft Windows bitmaps in Java applications](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip43.html).

Comment: this didn't work for me (not sure why it doesnt display in a Jlabel)