# How to display BMP Images in simple Java image viewer

Tags: java, image, display, bmp, viewer

I am newer to programming and am trying to get my image viewer program to display BMP images. The program works for JPEG and PNG images but not for BMP. I have commented out attempts I have made to make BMP work which I have found online. The methods I have found online all seem to convert the BMP to PNG. I would preferr for the image to stay a BMP but if that is not possible would still like to get it working where it converts to PNG. Aditionally, I know how to change the image window size but don't know what determines the size the image displays in or if there is a way to change that? I have included what I have so far below:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ImageViewer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new ImageViewerFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Image Viewer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}


class ImageViewerFrame extends JFrame {
JLabel label;
JFileChooser chooser;
JMenuBar menubar;
JMenu menu;
JMenuItem menuitem;

public ImageViewerFrame() {

    setSize(500,500); // set size of window

    label = new JLabel();
    add(label);

    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));

    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    menu = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(menu);

    menuitem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    menu.add(menuitem);

    menuitem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                //Image image = ImageIO.read

                String name = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();

                //Image image = ImageIO.read(name);
                //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(name);
                //JLabel test = new JLabel(icon);

                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(name)); //opens file

               // ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(name);
               // label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display BMP in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593830/display-bmp-in-jlabel)

Comment: What happens if you use `ImageIO.read(chooser.getSelectedFile())`? It should work fine. It does *not* work with a `String` containing a path though. It has to be a `File` object, or an `InputStream` (or a `URL`).